# isPrime Function - check if that num is a Prime Number or not - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, primes

i want to take a value from user using **prompt()** and check this value if prime number or not
the function must be named as **isPrime** and have one parameter named as **num**
i'm already write the code but the result is => **0 isn't a prime number** - **1 isn't a prime number** and ***3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or ..... is a prime number here i want a help to fix this mistake***

```
let insertedValue = prompt("enter your value" , "");

for (var i = 2; i < insertedValue; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}

const isPrime =  (num) => {
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
        alert(`${num} isn't a prime number`);
    } else if (num / 1 == num && num / num == 1 && num % i == 0) {
        console.log(`${num} isn't a prime number`);
    } else if (num / 1 == num && num / num == 1 && num % i != 0) {
        console.log(`${num} is a prime number`);
    }
}

isPrime(insertedValue);
```

Comment: unclear what your problem is exactly... And insertedValue is a string, not a number.

Comment: you arent passing i to your function.  if you are restricted to having just `num` as an arg then you need to loop within your funtion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can loop to check if the number is divisible by any integer from `2` to the square root of the number. If not, the number is prime.

```js
let insertedValue = +prompt("enter your value" , "");
const isPrime =  (num) => {
    if(num <= 1) return false;
    for(let i = 2; i * i <= num; i++)
      if(num % i === 0) return false;
    return true;
}
alert(isPrime(insertedValue) ? `${insertedValue} is a prime number` 
     : `${insertedValue} isn't a prime number`);
```